# IAB signed data with no orders in it

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've been using IAB in my app for several months now and I've noticed some of the signed data coming from IAB looks like this.  (Note I removed the signature for brevity).

```
{"signedData":"{\"nonce\":-5355169768522252731,\"orders\":[]}","signature":"xxx...."}
```

Notice there are no orders in this signed data response.  Does anyone know what would cause this message to get sent back from the IAB service?  It seems to have no value at all.

Comment: Are you seeing this on your own devices or somehow getting it from users in the field?

Comment: Also, check that the orders correspond to something you see in your merchant account.   People will try to hack IAP and often it shows up as an invalid signature.

Comment: This is in production using IAB 2.0 API.  It seems to come in batches, that is, I'll get a flurry of them (while also not getting any legit IAB purchases).  Then it will stop and I'll start getting legitimate responses.  It feels (though I have no proof), like it's an IAB server issue that periodically occurs.

Comment: When you look at your merchant account, are there legitimate purchases matching (in time) these incidents?

Comment: @BryantHarris Which version you are using? V2 or V3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `restoreTransactions()` will result in a message with empty orders if the users has not purchased anything.